# C++, no matching function for call to error

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Junior CS student here, struggling quite a bit.

This is the error I get:

```
main.cpp:45:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘yerlesimBirimi::isimAta()’
      obj1.isimAta();
                   ^
```

Below is my code. Could you help me see what I'm doing wrong?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class yerlesimBirimi {
public:
    string isim;
    int nufus;
    int dogumSayisi, olumSayisi;

    void isimAta (string _isim){
        cin >> _isim;
        isim = _isim;
    }

    void nufusAta (int _nufus){
        cin >> _nufus;
        nufus = _nufus;
    }

    void dogumAta (int _dogumSayisi){
        cin >> _dogumSayisi;
        dogumSayisi = _dogumSayisi;
    }

    void olumAta (int _olumSayisi){
        cin >> _olumSayisi;
        olumSayisi = _olumSayisi;
    }

    double dogumOrani();
    double olumOrani ();
};

double yerlesimBirimi::dogumOrani(){
    return dogumSayisi/nufus;
}

double yerlesimBirimi::olumOrani(){
    return olumSayisi/nufus;
}

int main (){
    yerlesimBirimi obj1;
    cout << "Yerlesim biriminin ismini giriniz:";
    obj1.isimAta();
    cout << "Nufusunu giriniz:";
    obj1.nufusAta();
    cout << "Dogum sayisini giriniz:";
    obj1.dogumAta();
    cout << "Olum sayisini giriniz:";
    obj1.olumAta();
    cout << obj1.isim << "--- Dogum Orani:" << obj1.dogumOrani << endl;
    cout << obj1.isim << "--- Olum Orani" << obj1.olumOrani << endl;
    yerlesimBirimi obj2;
    cout << "Yerlesim biriminin ismini giriniz:";
    cin >> obj2.isim;
    cout << "Nufusunu giriniz:";
    cin >> obj2.nufus;
    cout << "Dogum sayisini giriniz:";
    cin >> obj2.dogumSayisi;
    cout << "Olum sayisini giriniz:";
    cin >> obj2.olumSayisi;
    cout << "------------- Dogum Orani:" << obj2.dogumOrani<<endl;
    cout << "------------- Olum Orani:" << obj2.olumOrani<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You have `void isimAta (string _isim)` and you call `obj1.isimAta();` What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What's the problem there? I tried obj1.isimAta(string), obj1.isimAta(string _isim), obj1.isimAta (string K) and none worked. Please explain like I'm five.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining your `isimAta()`, `nufusAta()`, `dogumAta()`, and `olumAta()` class methods as all taking an input parameter, but then you don't actually pass in any value for those parameters, for instance:

```cpp
void isimAta (string _isim){ // <-- requires an input value!
    cin >> _isim;
    isim = _isim;
}

obj1.isimAta() // <-- no value passed in!
```

That is why you are getting the compiler error.

The way you are using the parameters, they need to be changed into local variables instead, eg:

```cpp
void isimAta (){ // <-- no parameter!
    string _isim; // <-- local variable instead!
    cin >> _isim;
    isim = _isim;
}

void nufusAta (){ // <-- no parameter!
    int _nufus; // <-- local variable instead!
    cin >> _nufus;
    nufus = _nufus;
}

void dogumAta (){ // <-- no parameter!
    int _dogumSayisi; // <-- local variable instead!
    cin >> _dogumSayisi;
    dogumSayisi = _dogumSayisi;
}

void olumAta (){ // <-- no parameter!
    int _olumSayisi; // <-- local variable instead!
    cin >> _olumSayisi;
    olumSayisi = _olumSayisi;
}
```

That will fix the compiler errors.

But, that behind said, you don't actually need those local variables at all. You can read directly into your class members instead, eg:

```cpp
void isimAta (){
    cin >> isim;
}

void nufusAta (){
    cin >> nufus;
}

void dogumAta (){
    cin >> dogumSayisi;
}

void olumAta (){
    cin >> olumSayisi;
}
```